# How to kick an NFS client from NFS server on AIX?

Tags: nfs, aix

We can see high NFS usage for a client that we want to kick off, but not affecting the other NFS clients. How can we do this? Only with using firewall?

Comment: Is there an explicit access list, or is it wide open?

Comment: if you don't have an explicit access list, then yes, I think you're down to a [firewall](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.security/ipsec_filters_aix.htm) or explicitly listing every client *except* that one, unexporting and re-exporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need bos.net.ipsec.rte to be able to use an iptables like solution.

check your current installation with:

```
michael@x071:[/home/michael]lslpp -L bos.net.ipsec.rte
  Fileset                      Level  State  Type  Description (Uninstaller)
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  bos.net.ipsec.rte         6.1.9.45    C     F    IP Security
```

If it is already installed, you can check if it is active, or inactive using:

Active:

```
michael@x071:[/home/michael]lsdev -C | grep ipsec
ipsec_v4    Available       IP Version 4 Security Extension
ipsec_v6    Available       IP Version 6 Security Extension
```

Inactive:

```
root@x064:[/]lsdev -C | grep ipsec
```

That is **no output**, meaning it has never been activated, or

```
root@x072:[/]lsdev -C | grep ipsec
ipsec_v4   Defined         IP Version 4 Security Extension
ipsec_v6   Defined         IP Version 6 Security Extension
```

some output meaning there maybe some configuration, but it has been deactivated.

Here are some examples of how you can switch on/off ipsec for v4 and-or v6 ipsec.

```
root@x072:[/]lsdev -C | grep ipsec
ipsec_v4   Defined         IP Version 4 Security Extension
ipsec_v6   Available       IP Version 6 Security Extension
root@x072:[/]mkdev -l ipsec_v4
ipsec_v4 Available
root@x072:[/]rmdev -l ipsec_v6
ipsec_v6 Defined
root@x072:[/]lsdev -C | grep ipsec
ipsec_v4   Available       IP Version 4 Security Extension
ipsec_v6   Defined         IP Version 6 Security Extension
```

Now to stopping nfs per client (defined as an IP address)

Let's take the IP address **192.168.111.222** as the address of the client I want to stop.
There are different actions that can be taken - permit and deny are the common ones - we can be a bit fancy though and use block-port that creates a new dynamic deny rule each time a port tries to connect - this way you can see how active the unique mount requests are:

We need to focus on port 2049

```
root@x072:[/]grep nfs /etc/services
nfsd-status      1110/tcp               # Cluster status info
nfsd-keepalive  1110/udp                # Client status info
picknfs          1598/tcp               # picknfs
picknfs          1598/udp               # picknfs
shiva_confsrvr  1651/tcp                # shiva_confsrvr
shiva_confsrvr  1651/udp                # shiva_confsrvr
#nfs                    2049/tcp                # Network File System - Sun Microsystems
#nfs                    2049/udp                # Network File System - Sun Microsystems
3d-nfsd          2323/tcp               # 3d-nfsd
3d-nfsd          2323/udp               # 3d-nfsd
mediacntrlnfsd  2363/tcp                # Media Central NFSD 
mediacntrlnfsd  2363/udp                # Media Central NFSD
```

Note: to use smit(ty) use:

```
smitty ipsec4
```

and then use Advanced...->Add

```
                         Add an IP Security Filter Rule

Type or select values in entry fields.
Press Enter AFTER making all desired changes.

                                                        [Entry Fields]
* Rule Action                                        [shun_port]             +
* IP Source Address                                  [192.168.111.222]
* IP Source Mask                                     [255.255.255.255]
  IP Destination Address                             [0.0.0.0]
  IP Destination Mask                                [0.0.0.0]
* Apply to Source Routing? (PERMIT/inbound only)     [yes]                   +
* Protocol                                           [tcp]                   +
* Source Port / ICMP Type Operation                  [any]                   +
* Source Port Number / ICMP Type                     [0]                      #
* Destination Port / ICMP Code Operation             [eq]                    +
* Destination Port Number / ICMP Type                [2049]                   #
* Routing                                            [local]                 +
* Direction                                          [inbound]               +
* Log Control                                        [no]                    +
* Fragmentation Control                              [0]                     +
* Interface                                          [all]                   +
  Expiration Time  (sec)                             [300]                    #
  Pattern Type                                       [none]                  +
  Pattern / Pattern File                             []
  Description                                        <g port on NFS request]
```

Or from the command line:

```
/usr/sbin/genfilt -v 4  -a 'S' -s '192.168.111.222' -m '255.255.255.255' -d '0.0.0.0' -M '0.0.0.0' -g 'y' -c 'tcp' -o 'any' -p '0' -O 'eq' -P '2049' -r 'L' -w 'I' -l 'N' -t '0' -i 'all' -e '300' -D 'block incoming port on NFS request'
```

And either in smit, or from the command line - activate the rule

```
mkfilt -v4 -u
```

and to see the configured rules

```
lsfilt -v4 -O
```

and to see any (maybe) dynamic rules

```
lsfilt -v4 -a -O
```

** Comment I cannot yet add: in case you need a change right NOW - as this only affects future connections to the port you can use the commands:

```
nfs.clean; sleep 2; rc.nfs
```

to stop, then restart nfs services. Note that

```
stopsrc -g nfs; startsrc -g nfs
```

does not start the daemons in the proper sequence

Comment: if there is no other solution, this looks OK! :)

Comment: I hope it does not look complex. I do not think so. But I think iptables are hard. Had I been using iptables rather than mkfilt since 1999 I might think this is hard ;)

Comment: Ugh - press enter and the comment goes... What I wanted to add is that ipsec is used by AIX hardening (using aixpert) - so ipsec should be installed and ready to go by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
netstat -an
```

then use `tcpkill` to send reset packets to both sides.

tcpkill uses same params as tcpdump

Comment: Wouldn't the client just reopen a new TCP connection immediately?  This action doesn't make it unmount the resource.

Comment: update exports / iptables for new connections

Comment: it sounds like their NFS server is running AIX, which I don't think provides iptables or tcpkill